# jQuery: Get count of members of an object inside an object

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, object

I output `json` data of a multidimensional array with `PHP` like this (have simplified it):

```
// query for education
$q = "SELECT ID, name, surname, email FROM education WHERE age='$age'";
$r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($r);

$data = array();

if($num_rows > 0) {
    $rows_education = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
      $row_array['ID'] = $row['ID'];
      $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
      $row_array['surname'] = $row['surname'];
      $row_array['email'] = $row['email'];
      array_push($rows_education, $row_array);
    }
  $data['success'] = true;
  $data['record']['computer'] = $rows_computer; // comes from another query
  $data['record']['education'] = $rows_education;
} else {
  $data['success'] = false;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

And on client side, I use this JS code:

```
    function View(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: "s_myfile.php?op=get",
        data : { 
          ID: e.data.record.ID
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(j)
        {
          console.log(j);

          var c = Object.keys(j.record.education).length;
          alert(c);

        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
  });
}
```

My problem is, that the Object.keys(j.record.education).length gives me the number of keys, which is 4. But I want to get the number of rows returned with the `mysql_query ($num_rows)`, which is a dynamic result. How can I get the number of objects (education) in (record) object?

Comment: You don't store that value in your return data.

Comment: Have updated the code, forgot the while loop.

Comment: I think you have a better chance of a good answer if you post the output of `console.log(j);`. Your question is about Javascript, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through object keys you use `Object.keys(ObjectToIterateThrough)`. But the type of `j.record.education` is (probably) already an array, so you can just access the length directly: `j.record.education.length`.

Below an example that illustrates the differences between array and object and how to achieve the same thing with both types:

```
var myObject = {
    uuid_1: { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 },
    uuid_2: { prop1: 3, prop2: 4 },
};
var myArray = [
    { uuid: 1, prop1: 1, prop2:2 },
    { uuid: 2, prop1: 3, prop2:4 },
];
// Iterate through object:
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(key => console.log(key, myObj[key]) );
// Iterate through array:
myArray.forEach(item => console.log(item.uuid, item) );
```